# ambiguous reference to member subscript after conversion of code from swift 2 to swift 3 in xcode 8

Tags: ios, arrays, swift3, code-migration

I'm new to swift programming. I am facing this issue after updating this code from swift 2 to swift 3

#### Swift 2 code was

```
let dicConversation = self.conversationListArray?[indexPath.row] as! NSMutableDictionary
```

now I converted successfully this code in swift 3 by splitting it into parts

#### Swift 3 code

```
let accountArrayDict = self.conversationListArray?[indexPath.row] as? Dictionary<String, Any>
let accountArray : [String : String] = accountArrayDict?["accounts"] as! [String : String]
```

code successfully converted in swift 3 but I don't know how to convert this line below:

```
cell.conversationTitle?.text = accountArray?[0]["displayName"] as? String
```

below this is what I have tried but showing error in first part. Second one is now okay

```
cell.conversationTitle?.text = accountArray[0] as![String]
let accountArray : [String] = accountArrayDict?["displayName"] as! [String]
```

Comment: Can you please print out the content of `self.conversationListArray` ?

Comment: dear sir @MidhunMP can i print out the content of conversationListArray with these error because program is build failed ?

Comment: Just comment out the code which have issues and just print that data only. I got the issue, but before posting an answer, it'll be good to see the structure of your data

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, **never** declare data source arrays for (non-optional) table views as optional.

```
var conversationListArray = [[String:Any]]()
```

This avoids a lot of question marks and type casts,
the compiler knows `accountArrayDict` is `[String:Any]`

```
let accountArrayDict = self.conversationListArray[indexPath.row]
```

The name `accountArray` implies that the type is an **array** so it's

```
let accountArray = accountArrayDict["accounts"] as! [[String : String]]
```

Then you can write

```
cell.conversationTitle?.text = accountArray[0]["displayName"]
```

Since the compiler knows that the inner dictionary has `String` values you get rid of this type cast, too. That's a good example why Swift native types are much more efficient than Foundation `NS(Mutable)...` collection types.

Nevertheless for a nested data model like this it's highly recommended to use a custom struct or class.

Comment: Thank you so much sir :) you are savior  thanks again  .